# Can't get specific data-point to pull from Yahoo Finance into Excel?

Tags: html, excel, vba, getelementbyid, innertext

I am trying to pull a very specific number from the Yahoo Finance page but am getting stuck. The link where I am trying to pull this information from is:

> http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL+Historical+Prices

I am interested in getting the **111.31** number that is listed near the top of that page in bold. I have written the following code to extract this information but every time I run it, it says "Object doesn't support this property or method". I suspect the error lies in the line where I use `getElementsByClass` and `getElementsById` to extract that data.

```
    Sub GetQuote()
    Dim IE As Object

     Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

     With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL+Historical+Prices"
        Do While .busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        With .document
            Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:05 AM#)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = .getElementsByClass("time_rtq_ticker").getElementsById("yfs_184_aapl").innerText

        End With

    End With

    Set IE = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Can you all please take a look and let me know where I went wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. I still get the same "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [getElementsByClassName method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975198(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a **collection** of one or more objects. You need to supply the index (i.e. *position*) of the element in the collection. Try,

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = .getElementsByClass("time_rtq_ticker")(0).getElementById("yfs_184_aapl").innerText
```

In fact, the `yfs_184_aapl` id is unique on that page. You only need,

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = .getElementById("yfs_184_aapl").innerText
```

Note that the [getElementById method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is singular, not `getElementsById`.

Comment: That worked great! Thanks so much for your help. Do you know of a good way in which I can learn about extracting data from the Internet using VBA? So far, I have been using google to find code that has already been written and trying to adapt that to suit my needs. However, that leads to problems because I do not really know what is going on. Is there a primer or book that covers the topic of extracting data from Internet using VBA?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know of any off the top of my head. There are tons of good code examples here that cover a wide range of situations. Keep in mind that sooner or later you will want to graduate to xmlHTTP objects and throw the Internet.Explorer object away.